# Subgroup of a doubly transitively acting group acts transitively

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-actions

> **Prop.** Let $G$ be a group that acts doubly transitively on $X$. Let $H\leq G$ be such that $|G:H| < |X|$. Then $H$ acts transitively on
> $X$.

I am trying to prove the proposition above. I know that since $G$ acts doubly transitively, for any $x_0\in X$, the stabilizer subgroup $G_{x_0}$ acts transitively on $X\setminus\{x_0\}$, but I don't know how could I make use of this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The index of $H$ in $G$ is usually denoted $|G:H|$ (or $[G:H]$), not $|H:G|$.

Comment: Where does this proposition come from?

Comment: If $G$ is doubly transitive, the stabilizer $G_{x_0}$ is transitive on $X \setminus \{x_0\}$. Why do you say it could be trivial?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin you are right, I made a mistake, which I've corrected now. Thanks!

Comment: @SeanEberhard I read something in my lecture notes, but I realize I misunderstood something, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G \le \mathrm{Sym}(X)$ be a $2$-transitive group where $X$ is finite. Let $S \subset X$ be a proper nonempty subset and let $N = \{g \in G : S^g = S\}$ be the setwise stabilizer of $S$. By the orbit--stabilizer theorem, $|G:N| = |\mathcal B|$, where $\mathcal B = \{S^g : g \in G\}$. Since $G$ is $2$-transitive, every pair of elements $x, y \in X$ appears in the same number of blocks $B \in \mathcal B$. Hence by [Fisher's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_inequality) $|G:N| = |\mathcal B| \ge |X|$.

Therefore if $H \le G$ has index $|G:H| < |X|$ then $H$ is not contained in the setwise stabilizer of a proper nonempty subset, i.e., $H$ is transitive.

---

For an example with equality in which $H$ is not just a point stabilizer, consider $G = \mathrm{PGL}_3(q)$ acting on the $q^2+q+1$ points of the projective plane of order $q$, and consider the setwise stabilizer of a line.

For a counterexample in which $G$ is only primitive, consider $G = S_n \wr S_2$ acting on $[n]^2$ and let $H \cong S_{n-1} \times S_n$ be a row stabilizer. Then $[G:H] = 2n < n^2$ for $n > 2$. Another example is given by $G = S_n$ acting on the $\binom n 2$ subsets of size $2$ and $H = S_{n-1}$.

Comment: That's clever! I haven't seen that result before.